# Pega Debugging tools

Tags: pega

Just started with Pega and I often get errors while previewing the application I build.   Is there any way to get more detailed errors/logs rather than just "java.lang.NullPointerException"?

I'm trying to get a better understanding rather than fix any specific error.    Is it possible to view the underlying code that's created when building applications with Pega App/Dev studio?  Is there a console or error log that would give me a better way to pinpoint where I went wrong?  Is there any resources or guides on how to debug better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two built-in tools that will help you with debugging: [Tracer](https://community.pega.com/knowledgebase/articles/application-development/84/application-debugging-using-tracer-tool) and [Clipboard](https://community.pega.com/knowledgebase/articles/application-development/84/clipboard-tool). The former shows you which rules are involved, the order in which they are called, and data passed in/modified by certain rules, as well as the entire stack to help you track down any error. You can decide to show/hide rules, set breakpoints, and more.

The Clipboard allows you to inspect data that is associated with an application - for example fields, data pages, and much more.